# Como resolver vários erros deste código?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Digitei este programa do livro que aborda classes e deu erro. Como resolver?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Efetua_calculo{
private:
    double total;
    double soma;
    double divide;

public:
     void mostra_calculo (void){
    cout << "Resultado das funcoes soma() e divide() e :" << endl;
    cout << soma() << endl;
    cout << divide() << endl;
    return;
    }
};
double Efetua_calculo::soma(){

int valor1 = 2;
int valor2 = 3;
total = valor1 + valor2;
return (total);

}
double Efetua_calculo::divide(){
int valor1 = 2;
int valor2 = 3;

total = (double) valor1/valor2;

return(total);
}

int main()
{
Efetua_calculo calculo;
calulo.mostra_calculo();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o erro que foi retornado? Nos dê mais detalhes @Rodolfo

Comment: Edita a tua pergunta a põe a saída do erro lá. Fica mais fácil de te ajudar se soubermos o que está acontecendo.

Comment: de uma olhada na edição.

Comment: -1 pelo mau título e por usar uma "foto" pra apresentar o problema, quando (o que dificulta pessoas com mesmo problema encontrarem está pergunta)

Comment: As pessoas precisam parar de votar roboticamente e analisar o problema. Não é só erro de digitação que tem aí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem erros de digitação. Talvez alguns bem graves. Talvez o exemplo do livro seja bem ruim e não funcione mesmo. O que aí seria bom abandonar livro tão ruim. O exemplo é bem ruim também para aprender programar direito. Tem erros conceituais nele, além da estrutura ruim.

Não sei se resolvi o problema de forma adequada mas assim funciona:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Efetua_calculo {
private:
    double total; //do jeito que está este membro não deveria existir
public:
    void mostra_calculo(); //aqui só cabe a declaração e não a definição
    double soma(); //declarei essa função que não estava declarada
    double divide(); //idem, estava declarada como variável
};
double Efetua_calculo::soma(){
    int valor1 = 2;
    int valor2 = 3;
    total = valor1 + valor2;
    return (total);
}
double Efetua_calculo::divide(){
    int valor1 = 2;
    int valor2 = 3;
    total = (double) valor1/valor2;
    return(total);
}
void Efetua_calculo::mostra_calculo(){ //trouxe a implementação p/ cá
    cout << "Resultado das funcoes soma() e divide() e :" << endl;
    cout << soma() << endl;
    cout << divide() << endl;
    return;
}
int main() {
    Efetua_calculo calculo;
    calculo.mostra_calculo(); //tinha erro de digitação aqui
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2Jpruy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oycznbqb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/CalcClass.cpp).

Comment: O que seriam estes  erros conceituais?

Comment: Eu tive e joguei fora, não aprendi por ele não. A principal é a maneira como monta a classe. Cria uma variável de instância para guardar valores que só são usados localmente nos métodos. Tem pequenos problemas que ensinam um estilo ruim de codificação. Mesmo p/ algo que esteja sendo apenas didático (o que nem é). Mas tinha tantos problema que nem sei qual era o objetivo real disto. Note como o código está bem diferente. E poderia mudar bem mais para ficar melhor.

Comment: aprendi C e C++ por conta própria e vi que ele não separou as classes em arquivos separados

Comment: Para fins de exercício em algo que não será usado em outro contexto, não é necessário separar. Na verdade desse jeito é até melhor assim. Só separa quando tem que separar.